# Как передать переменную в подключаемый файл?

Tags: php

include ('header.php') как мне передать в шаблон хедер переменную с значением(true или false) ? 
В зависимости от того что мне пришло в шаблон хедера я буду делать те или иные действия.

Comment: Никак не надо передавать, она и так там уже есть

Comment: То есть я в шаблоне header.php могу прописать 
`<div class="<?php ($variable == true) ? 'my_class' : '' ?>"`

Comment: Советую не делать такую дичь, поскольку это полностью нарушает принцип единой ответственности и делает код уязвимым к ошибкам. Делайте это с помощью тех же шаблонизаторов: blade, twig и т.д., но никак не через include.

Comment: так а как по другому на wordpress можно сделать ?

Comment: @РомаЛытарь написать свой православный wordpress c блэк-джеком и шлюхами :)

Comment: =) Опять велосипед создавать)